# prerender.io node.js prerender server on azure

Tags: node.js, azure, prerender

I'm having an issue setting up the prerender.io rendering server https://github.com/prerender/prerender.git on an Azure website.

I have created a blank Node.js Azure project in VS2015 and the node.js server starts fine and renders content fine locally.

The issue is when I deploy to Azure I am getting an internal server error which is the following:

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: write ENOTSUP
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at ChildProcess.target._send (internal/child_process.js:606:18)
    at ChildProcess.target.send (internal/child_process.js:507:12)
    at sendHelper (cluster.js:699:8)
    at send (cluster.js:501:5)
    at cluster.js:477:7
    at SharedHandle.add (cluster.js:82:3)
    at queryServer (cluster.js:469:12)
    at Worker.onmessage (cluster.js:425:7)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (cluster.js:713:8)
```

From the error I can only suspect there is an issue with the request and clustering mechanism. I emailed prerender.io to see if they have any insight as to what is happening. I've also searched high and low on the web but can't seem to find any similar issues to use as a reference.

All the node.js project defaults remain. I've only imported the prerender.io node.js code into the vs2015 project. As I noted, it's working locally.

Comment: does the prerender package/middleware talk to any of their servers in the backend ? if so may be there is some firewall or connectivity issue. I am guessing that you are publishing this site in azure web apps.

Comment: I determined that Cluster isn't supported by IISNode as noted here by the author of IISNode. Here is a GitHub conversation about the matter https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/195

Answer (score 1):

From my testing, I found I could run prerender.IO on my local and the Azure website using powershell.

I installed the package and used the server.js code as following:

```
var prerender = require('./lib');

var server = prerender({
    workers: process.env.PRERENDER_NUM_WORKERS,
    iterations: process.env.PRERENDER_NUM_ITERATIONS
});


server.use(prerender.sendPrerenderHeader());
// server.use(prerender.basicAuth());
// server.use(prerender.whitelist());
server.use(prerender.blacklist());
// server.use(prerender.logger());
server.use(prerender.removeScriptTags());
server.use(prerender.httpHeaders());
// server.use(prerender.inMemoryHtmlCache());
// server.use(prerender.s3HtmlCache());

server.start()
```

Then, I deployed this project on Azure Web App service. I ran the server.js in kudu panel with the powershell, like this image:
[image]

Another questions, which version did you used? I used node.js version was V4.2.3.

Comment: Hi will, did you run their middleware or the render server? I was attempting to run the render server and I was on Node 6.2. I was under a tight deadline to get something going for a project so we went the VM way as I didn't have any time to start modifying the open source project. Interesting comment though.

Answer (score 1):

> did you run their middleware or the render server? I was attempting to run the render server and I was on Node 6.2. I was under a tight deadline to get something going for a project so we went the VM way

Appreciate your post for raising this concern, I would like to confirm that Prerender is not supported on Azure web app currently due to prerender uses cluster module that doesn't support named pipe connections while azure web app uses named pipe connections to connect iis with node.exe. We will continue to look into this issue and keep this thread updated once the workaround and solution are figured out. Please feel free to let me know if you have any further concerns.